# Popper Email Notifier not working

Tags: 10.10, notification

Using Maverick 64bit

I downloaded Popper Email Notifier today. Installed it from the v023 deb.
https://launchpad.net/popper

I configured it, and the TEST tab shows I configured everything properly. I can't get Popper to appear in the notification menu. I have restarted gnome-pannel, restarted my computer, reinstalled the app. No luck. I checked the /usr/share/indicators/messages/applications/ folder, and there's only the defaults there.

Anyone know how to fix this? Even if someone knows what file I can drop into that folder to make it work that'd be great.

Edit: I wonder if it's because I removed the evolution-indicator package?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm the developer of Popper. From what you are writing I see that there must be an issue with your indicator menu configuration. Maybe you removed too much when you removed the evolution-indicator package. Please test the following:

Go to: http://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/allgemeiner-email-benachrichtiger/43/
There is a test script (indi.py) and a desktop file (popper.desktop) at the bottom of the page. Download both and store it in a temporary directory, e.g.: /home/user/test

Open a terminal, go to this directory and run: python indi.py

Now you should see a new entry in your indicator menu with numbers counting up every 5 seconds. If you don't see the entry in your indicator menu, you have an issue with the indicator menu and not with Popper. If you see the entry, it is a Popper issue.

Anyway, please do the test and come back with the results in: launchpad.net/popper

Comment: Thanks for the response. I ran that script and I got a "Popper" entry with a list of numbers after it. I guess I'll post on the launchpad.net/popper forums or file a bug?

Comment: Yes, go to https://answers.launchpad.net/popper and open a question (button 'Answers' on top middle of the screen) please. Then we can continue solving your problem at that place. Thanks

Comment: I asked a question on launchpad. Here's the link so others may easily find it: https://answers.launchpad.net/popper/+question/137337 Thanks for the help rhersel.

Answer (score 0):

- Open **.popper** folder located in your home directory(`$HOME`)
- Open **popper.cfg** file
- Removing the Archived folder for Gmail in `popper.cfg` worked for me.